# Batch File to delete a Folder in all users Home Directories

Tags: copy, cmd

I need to delete a folder in all users home directories called 'My Settings' and then I need to copy all the contents of their directories to their new locations on a new server. Does anyone have any idea how would be best to go about doing this, and could help me right a script to complete this task?

I am using Windows Server 2003 R2, I final Managed this by running the 'dir' command and getting list of the users and then placed it into excel and then generated an indervidual command that would complete the task for me 'rmdir \servername\user$\MySettings'

Regards
Tom

Comment: Which operating system?  (Also, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?)

Comment: The word "batch" generally denotes DOS or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Windows Server 2003 R2, I final Managed this by running the 'dir' command and getting list of the users and then placed it into excel and then generated an indervidual command that would complete the task for me 'rmdir \servername\user$\MySettings'